# Can a function's return be passed into the ReactDOM render as a variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is the correct way to pass a function's return into the ReactDOM render? Below is the code I currently have that is throwing an error.

```
var customerFunc = () => {
  axios('/customers')
  .then(response => {
    var customersArray = response.data; 
    console.log("Customers Response:", customersArray)
    return customersArray;
  })
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App initialCustomers={customerFunc()}/>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Previous to adding this function, I was passing in dummy data in an array into initialCustomers (`(initialCustomers={customersArray}`) and it worked perfectly. I am now trying to hit an endpoint and return the array of customers in the function (the `customerFunc` function). The Customers Response console log in the function returns an array of customers, with the same fields the dummy data array had so I know it is not a problem with retrieving the data.

However, every time I pass in the customer function into initialCustomers, it returns the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

And when I console log within the App component (`{console.log("Initial Customers:", this.props.initialCustomers)}`) it does indeed return undefined. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `customerFunc` is an async function. `.render` get's called, but it doesn't wait for your promise to finish and return the data. You can use [`async/await`](https://medium.com/@zwacky/add-es7-async-await-support-into-your-non-bleeding-edge-build-process-ad0dded0d002) if you are using babel, or you can move the render call into the promise success handler:

Using async/await:

```
async const customerFunc = () => {
    axios('/customers')
    .then( await response => {
        console.log("Customers Response:", response.data)
        return response.data;
    });
}
// This will wait for the promise to resolve and return the data
const customersArray = customerFunc();

ReactDOM.render(
    <App initialCustomers={customersArray}/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Or nest the render call in the promise:

```
const customerFunc = () => {
    axios('/customers')
    .then( response => {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App initialCustomers={response.data}/>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be do the axios call in the App. So render would be

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and then in the App.jsx

```
class App extends React.Component() {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // state variable
        };
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         // axios call and set state
     }
     render() {
         // use the state
     }
}
```